# Regex: Select empty spaces from a particular tab and replace them with one single space

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

hello and Happy new year !

have a little problem with more then 2000 .html files. I need to select all empty spaces from the next particular tag, and to replace with just one space.

`<p class="test_formal"> This is my text    <em>and all of  this</em> I have    to go home .</p>`

My regex is not very good :(

Search: `(?s)(?:\G)|<p class="text_formal">).*?|.*(?=</p>)|+\h`

Replace by: `(Leave one space)`

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^<p class="text_formal">|\G)\K\s*(\S+)`
- Replace with: `$1`     # a space then $1
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                             # start non capture group
    ^                           # beginning of line
    <p class="text_formal">     # literally
  |                             # OR
    \G                          # restart from last match position
)                               # end group
\K                              # forget all we have seen until this position
\s*                             # 0 or more spaces
(\S+)                           # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
 <p class="test_formal"> This is my text <em>and all of this</em> I have to go home .</p>
```

Comment: Toto, `$1 # a space then $1` means `$1 $1` ? Are you sure isnt it `$1 $2` ? Can you make an example on https://regex101.com  ?  I don't think it is working. Besides, seems that the regex put all the lines in a single line. try regex on more same lines

Comment: @RobRob: I mean the replacement part is a space followed by `$1`.  Have a look at the duplicate question.

Comment: yes, ok, the problem is that regex moves all lines on a single line. And, it is not select only the particular tab, but all tags :)  https://regex101.com/r/ybSQFD/1

Comment: @RobRob: I can't do more, sorry. Look at the duplicate question. If it doesn't work, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: something about this will be more easily, if is possible: Search: `<p class="test_formal">[^\S\r\n]+(.*)</p>` Replace by: `(leave one space)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the part in which you want to make changes
2. Ctrl+H
3. Find what: `+` (space and plus sign)
4. Replace with:  (just space)
5. Check `In selection` (or press Alt+I)
6. Click on `Replace all` button (or press Alt+A)

That's all :)

Comment: I have more then 2000 .html files. Cannot do this :)

Comment: This will replace multiple spaces everywhere in the file. They want to replace ONLY inside `<p..> ... </p>`